# How do you copy a specific git commit to the staging area?

Tags: git

I want to copy the last commit from one branch (ie `branch-one`) to the staging area of another branch (ie `branch-two`). Is this possible and if so how is it done?

Comment: Use `git checkout`.  To prevent it from switching branches / detaching HEAD, check out specific files, instead of the entire branch: `git checkout commit-ID -- files...`.  To check out every file, use `.` in the project root as the specific file: `git checkout commit -- .`.  (Note: this of course also writes to working directory.)

Comment: that makes perfect sense torek if you post the answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `git checkout` command writes through the index/staging-area to the work directory, so checking out files does the job (though it updates the work directory whether you want that or not).

The problem, of course, is that `git checkout commit` switches branches, or detaches HEAD.  The trick to avoid this is to check out specific files, which avoids this branch-switching:

```
git checkout branch-one -- path/to/file.ext
```

If you check out the entire tree, you'll get all the files.  Assuming you're in the top level directory:

```
git checkout branch-one -- .
```

will do the trick.

One other caveat: this will not *remove* from the staging area any file that does *not* exist in `branch-one`.  If you want that as well, start by removing everything (the staging area will get repopulated by checking out all the files in the other branch):

```
git rm -rf .
git checkout branch-one -- .
```

(adjust as needed if you don't want to copy the other branch's .gitignore, etc; note that you can restore specific files from `branch-two`, aka `HEAD`, with:

```
git checkout HEAD -- path
```

if desired).

(As usual, be sure the state of the work directory is clean before doing this.)

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the destination branch and clear your staging area.
Then use

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit <commit hash>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you just want the changes from that single commit (not its entire branch) then

```
git cherry-pick *commit-id*
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Note: this will merge the changes in (as opposed to just copying the files involved)

Answer (score 1):

If you merge the two branches and then perform a soft reset, in the staging area you get the commits in `branch-one` that were ahead of `branch-two`. It's not the correct answer to the question, but it's actually what I ended up needing...

```
git checkout branch-two
git merge branch-one
git reset --soft @^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset branch-one .
```

`git reset <commit> <paths>` tells git to update the index for each `path` listed to the state it had at `commit`, without doing anything to the currently checked out branch or work tree. We use `.` here to mean the current directory, and therefore the entire repo.

Comment: @torek Indeed, it's basically the same as your answer, except that using `reset` instead of `checkout` avoids touching the work tree. OP didn't say which he actually wants, so it's anyone's guess which is right.